# Wordpress Digg-Like Voting System Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I just found out about [BuddyPress](http://buddypress.org/) (a collection of plugins that convert a [WordPress MU](http://mu.wordpress.org/) install into a social network) and now I was wondering if there are any Digg-like voting plugins for WordPress.  This would eventually integrate into a BuddyPress website, where the site members would submit, vote and comment on stories (much like Digg).

I have a feeling I will end up having to build this from scratch, but since the site will be built on WordPress, I was wondering if there were any plugins already available that add this functionality.  So far I have come up empty in my search.  I did find a Wordpress blog that had this functionality [WpVote](http://wpvote.com/).  It even creates thumbnails of the story webpage automatically (I'm assuming) using [websnapr](http://www.websnapr.com/).  I browsed through the page source and didn't seem to find any hints of a WP plugin that they are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BuddyPress Links is what you're looking for:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/buddypress-links/

Answer (score 7):

I've successfully used [TDO Mini Forms](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tdo-mini-forms/) for user submissions combined with [Vote it up](http://www.tevine.com/projects/voteitup/) to build a digg-style site.

You can create a "top votes" page using the *MostVotedAllTime_Widget()* function from Vote it up, or use the SortVotes() or GetVoteArray() functions to build and style your own top votes list in a customised page template.

You'll find the full list of available functions in /vote-it-up/votingfunctions.php

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try:

[Pligg Voting CMS](http://www.pligg.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Pligg seems to have the features I want, but getting it to play nicely with Wordpress (synonymous accounts and logins) might be rough (although possible).  I could easily see this as a great solution if it was for a site dedicated to just this type of service.

Answer (score 1):

when i was start to build my own social bookmarking, i using voteitup plugin but if you want to build your own vote button you can visit bavotasan.com and search post **"simple-voting for-wordpress-with-php-and-jquery"**
take a look at my own social bookmarking using it : http://nestdev.com

Answer (score 1):

http://prothemedesign.com/themes/nominate-for-wordpress/

is a premium theme I've come across but never used.  It's a WP version of Digg and I believe pretty good.

Personally I use Drigg which is a Drupal version of Digg.  See it in action here: http://weblinks.myfriendshotel.com Unfortunately, however, WebSnapr have just changed their code so the site is no longer showing thumbanails but hopefully as a 'non-programmer' I'll find a solution soon...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

http://www.tevine.com/projects/voteitup/

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the best Wordpress solution.  It doesn't support all of the features like placing the top posts on the front page, but it's close.  Many others are attempting to do the same thing as me, and I believe a sufficient plugin based on this one will eventually be created.

Comment: Any news? I have been looking for a nice voting plugin as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think [wpvote][1] use drigg module for drupal. I've just found  buddypress plugin which has similiar function like digg social bookmarking. [more detail](http://wpmu.org/buddypress-links-new-must-have-component-allows-rich-media-embedding/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant or not but the theme used for WPVote.com has now been released on Pro Theme Design - http://prothemedesign.com/themes/nominate-for-wordpress/